# skip certain validation method in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using **Rails v2.3**

If I have a **model**:

```
class car < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :method_1, :method_2, :method_3

  ...
  # custom validation methods
  def method_1
    ...
  end

  def method_2
    ...
  end

  def method_3
    ...
  end
end
```

As you see above, I have **3 custom validation methods**, and I use them for model validation.

If I have another method in this model class which save an new instance of the model like following:

```
# "flag" here is NOT a DB based attribute
def save_special_car flag
   new_car=Car.new(...)

   new_car.save #how to skip validation method_2 if flag==true
end
```

I would like to skip the validation of `method_2` in this particular method for saving new car, **how to skip the certain validation method?**

Comment: Does your 'special car' have any attribute that can differentiate it from non-special cars? That would make this simple.

Comment: Have you gone over the [conditional validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#conditional-validation) docs?

Comment: Hi, I updated my post for the method to save a special car. Basically, i have a "flag" parameter pass to the method, and if "flag" is true, I would like to skip the validation of method_2

Comment: @ Dave, I have gone over that. But what I want to achieve is in a method level, I am wondering is there any possibility to do it in method level, and how.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Update your model to this

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base

  # depending on how you deal with mass-assignment
  # protection in newer Rails versions,
  # you might want to uncomment this line
  # 
  # attr_accessible :skip_method_2

  attr_accessor :skip_method_2 

  validate :method_1, :method_3
  validate :method_2, unless: :skip_method_2

  private # encapsulation is cool, so we are cool

    # custom validation methods
    def method_1
      # ...
    end

    def method_2
      # ...
    end

    def method_3
      # ...
    end
end
```

Then in your controller put:

```
def save_special_car
   new_car=Car.new(skip_method_2: true)
   new_car.save
end
```

If you're getting `:flag` via params variable in your controller, you can use

```
def save_special_car
   new_car=Car.new(skip_method_2: params[:flag].present?)
   new_car.save
end
```

Comment: That `attr_writer` should be `attr_accessor` or you'll get an `undefined local variable or method 'skip_method'` error. Or you could write your own reader function like `skip_method?`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer ..I searched a lot for this.For anyone else who might come across this ,I think you'll get a MassAssignment error if you do it like that . You can avoid the error by doing like so:`new_car= Car.new` ,   `new_car.skip_method_2= params[:flag].present?`

Comment: @lnreddy thanks for pointing out the mass assignment error. I've updated the answer to newer Rails versions.

Answer (score 19):

The basic usage of conditional validation is:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :method_1
  validate :method_2, :if => :perform_validation?
  validate :method_3, :unless => :skip_validation?

  def perform_validation?
    # check some condition
  end

  def skip_validation?
    # check some condition
  end

  # ... actual validation methods omitted
end
```

Check out the docs for more details.

Adjusting it to your screnario:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :method_1, :method_3
  validate :method_2, :unless => :flag?

  attr_accessor :flag

  def flag?
    @flag
  end    

  # ... actual validation methods omitted
end

car = Car.new(...)
car.flag = true
car.save
```

Comment: Actually, flag is not a DB based attribute...So...any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Another technique, which applies more to a migration script than application code, is to redefine the validation method to not do anything:

```
def save_special_car
   new_car=Car.new
   new_car.define_singleton_method(:method_2) {}
   new_car.save
end
```

`#method_2` is now redefined to do nothing on the instance `new_car`.

Answer (score 0):

Use block in your validation something like :

```
validates_presence_of :your_field, :if =>  lambda{|e| e.your_flag ...your condition}
```

Answer (score 0):

With rails 6.x+ I think you can call `.save` or `.valid?` with a context attribute, like `.save(:a_context)` and, on the model side, use a validation like:

```
validate :method_2, on: :a_context
```

Ref: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#on

Answer (score -5):

Depending on weather flag is true of false, use the method `save(false)` to skip validation.

Comment: `save(false)` will skip entire validation, not just one method.

Comment: Also it is `save(validate: false)`, not `save(false)`

Comment: it's `save(false)` in Rails v2.3