# Passing custom options to .save rails to skip validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model, skip

I'm looking to pass logic to a model when attempting to save in order to disable specific validations.

I know of other solutions such as this one: [skip certain validation method in Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881712/skip-certain-validation-method-in-model)
This involves putting a temporary attribute on a model which I want to avoid.

I'd rather that has a solution that ends up looking like this:

```
@my_model.save(:skip_name_validation => true)
```

^ Is something like this possible in Rails 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For sure you can do this by performing a trick like:

```
class YourModel
  attr_accessor :skip_name_validation
  validate :validate_method, unless: :skip_name_validation
end
```

Now you can use it like:

```
@my_model.save(:skip_name_validation => true)
```

Comment: That was easier than expected. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Passing the attribute to `#save` as suggested in [Hieu Pham's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39711388/2514714) did not work for me.

I had to do it this way:

```rb
@my_model.skip_name_validation = true
@my_model.save
```

This implies the same setup as suggested previously, i.e. using `attr_accessor` to define the `skip_name_validation` attribute on the model.